# Встраивание командной строки в CustomTkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, customtkinter

Нужно сделать программу, в которой можно взаимодействовать с CMD через Custom Tkinter. Думаю можно использовать textbox.

Comment: Думаю вы можете сперва попробовать реализовать свою идею самостоятельно, а если что-то не получится, дополните вопрос своей реализацией кода.

Answer (score 0):

Да, вы можете использовать `Text` виджет из `Tkinter` (или аналогичный виджет из `customtkinter`) для создания текстового поля, которое будет отображать вывод командной строки. Вот пример того, как это можно сделать:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk
import subprocess

def execute_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return output.decode('utf-8'), error.decode('utf-8')

class CmdApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.text_box = ctk.CTkTextbox(self)
        self.text_box.pack()

        self.entry = ctk.CTkEntry(self)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self.run_command)

    def run_command(self, event):
        command = self.entry.get()
        output, error = execute_command(command)

        self.text_box.insert('end', output)
        self.text_box.insert('end', error)

        self.entry.delete(0, 'end')

app = CmdApp()
app.mainloop()
```

В этом примере создается новое приложение `CTk`, а затем создается `CTkText` виджет и `CTkEntry` виджет. Когда пользователь вводит команду в `CTkEntry` виджет и нажимает Enter, команда выполняется, а вывод отображается в `CTkText` виджет.

Я не стал сильно заморачиваться с дизайном, но это как пример решения вашей задачи подходит. Надеюсь что я решил вашу проблему :)

Comment: Вы, похоже, совсем не заморачиваетесь. "AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'CTkText'. Did you mean: 'CTkTextbox'?"

Comment: Странно, у меня всё выполняется, возможно у нас разные версии customtkinter, не обесценивайте пожалуйста мою помощь, я стараюсь

Comment: Да, действительно, извините за мои ошибки, я сделал правку, теперь всё должно работать

Comment: Что значит "должно работать"? Вам вломы, что ли проверить свой код? 
 Запустите его и введите любую команду cmd, что выдает?